# Changing value of constant object with pointer

Tags: c++

There is such code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  const int a = 2;
  int* ptr = (int*)&a;
  *ptr = 3;
  std::cout << &a << " " << ptr << " " << a << " " << *ptr << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0xbf88d51c 0xbf88d51c 2 3
```

Why these two values differ? What does it here happen?

Comment: You've invoked undefined behavior here, by attempting to change a `const` variable, so any explanation would be valid only for your particular compiler.  As far as the Standard goes, any values printed are just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* ptr = (int*)&a;
```

This is dangerous (this itself doesn't invoke UB, though). But this,

```
*ptr = 3;
```

This invokes undefined behavior (UB), because you're attempting to modify the `const` object pointing to by `ptr`. UB means anything could happen. Note that `a` is truly a const object.

§7.1.5.1/4 (C++03) says,

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, **any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.**

```
 [Example:

 [...]

const int* ciq = new const int (3); // initialized as required
int* iq = const_cast<int*>(ciq);    // cast required
*iq = 4;                            // undefined: modifies a const object
```

Comment: Isn't the line `*ptr = 3` that invokes the UB? What's wrong with getting the address of a `const int`?

Comment: If that line resulted in undefined behavior, `const_cast` would be pretty worthless.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: I think you're right. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Dennis: *If* it were UB to create a non-const pointer to a const object, then `const_cast` would still be useful for removing cv-qualification from (for example) a `const int*` that in fact points to an non-const int object. But since that line wasn't UB, we can say "if it were UB, then X" for any X, and be correct ;-)

Comment: It is illegal to take the address of an integral constant expression.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose: const_cast can only be safely used on variables that were not defined const in the first place.  If you have a non const variable that is passed as a const reference into a function, then you can safely use const_cast to remove the constness.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Can you further explain what you mean? I don't see in the code anywhere where the address of an integral constant expression is obtained, only the address of an integral constant variable `a` (funny constant variables... should have said constant *lvalue-expression*)

Comment: There's a minefield of terminology here. The expression `a` "is" an integral constant expression. But the expression `a` also "is" an lvalue expression denoting an object, whose address can be taken no problem. So `a` can be used in a context that requires an ICE, but also can be used in a context (such as unary `&`) that requires an lvalue. You can't take the address of an rvalue, whether it's an ICE or not, but there's a difference between the expression `a` in a context that causes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and the expression `a` in a context that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do things like this. It's undefined behavior.

If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge (c)

Answer (score 1):

I have a hypothesis that I have not tested:

Compiler set aside an address for a (0xbf88d51c), and fills it with 2.  int *ptr gets set to that address, and *ptr = 3 put 3 at that address.  So *ptr now points to a 3.  But when it comes across the value a, compiler hard codes the "2", as though you'd said `#define a 2`.

One way to verify is to pull up the resulting assembly code.

By the way, I know it's undefined behavior, but so what?  The OP asking WHY it happens.

Comment: The *why* is irrelevant, since the *why* might change from compiler to compiler.

Comment: The question "why?" can be answered in more than one way.  "It's undefined behavior" is shorthand for "It's undefined behavior, so the compiler can do whatever the hell it wants."  And that is a perfectly valid, and far more relevant answer to the question "Why do these two values differ?", especially when no compiler, settings or architecture other than "c++" were specified.

Comment: The OP asked, so it's relevant.  The OP never stated that "I'm putting this code in a big important project."  Otherwise, I agree.  Don't do it.  It's undefined, dangerous, etc.  I just suggested a possible reason why it happens.

Comment: @Mark:  The OP didn't specify a compiler.  Without knowing which compiler was used, and possibly which version and the compile flags in use, we can't know.  We can only speculate.  You are correct in that the compiler can substitute `2` for `a` anywhere in `a`'s scope and be in conformance with the Standard.

Answer (score 1):

That's because compiler replaces `... " " << a << " " ...` with `... " " << 2 << " " ...`.

It does so to avoid reading `a`'s value from memory when it's already know, constant and can be added right to assembler instruction.

Comment: yea, you're right. It's fragment from assembly for printing a: movl $2, 4(%esp); movl %eax, (%esp); call _ZNSolsEi. It indeed doesn't read from memory, just put there value 2.